# How do i set a cell value in javafx tablecell after a drag and drop event is complete?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, tableview

I'm designing an application that allows a drag and drop on `TableView` cells.

However, once the drag and drop is complete and the values of the cells switched successfully, a double-click on the cells where drag and drop has been effected makes the cells change back to their original text before drag and drop.

Help me solve this issue. The following code is used to set `cellFactoryValue` for all the cells. I am new to javafx.

```
private void setCellFactoryForColumns(TableColumn<TimeTable, String> col)
{
    col.setCellFactory((TableColumn<TimeTable, String> e) -> {
        TableCell<TimeTable, String> cell = new TableCell<TimeTable, String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        };

        col.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<TimeTable, String> t) -> {
            ((TimeTable)t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setDay(t.getNewValue());
        });

        cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(cell.getText());
            db.setContent(content);
            cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"
                        + "-fx-text-fill: white;");
            cell.startEdit();
            cell.setText("Dragged");

            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) ->{
            if(event.getGestureSource() != cell &&
                    event.getDragboard().hasString())
            {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;"
                        + "-fx-text-fill: white;");
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) ->{
           if(event.getGestureSource() != cell &&
                   event.getDragboard().hasString()){
               cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
           } 
           event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {
           cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
           event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if(db.hasString())
            {
                holdData = cell.getText();
                cell.setText(db.getString());
                success = true;
            }

            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        });

        cell.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) ->{
           if(event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE)
           {
               cell.setText(holdData);
           }
           event.consume();
        });
        return cell;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the text in the cell, not the property of the item. Therefore every time a new item is assigned to the `TableCell`, the old value is used as text.

This also happens, if you scroll the cell containing a item out of view.

To fix this replace the

```
cell.setText(db.getString());
```

and

```
cell.setText(holdData);
```

statements in the `onDragDone`/`onDragDropped` handlers with

```
update(cell, db.getString());
```

and

```
update(cell, holdData);
```

respectively and implement the `update` method like this:

```
static void update(TableCell<TimeTable, String> cell, String newValue) {
    ((TableRow<TimeTable>)cell.getTableRow()).getItem().setDay(newValue);
    // the below line would be needed, if the setter does not trigger
    // a update of the ObservableValue returned by the cellValueFactory
    // cell.getTableView().refresh();
}
```

In case your `cellValueFactory` returns a `WritableProperty` that allows writing to the item, the method can be written more general as

```
static <I,P>void update(TableCell<I, P> cell, P newValue) {
    WritableValue<P> property = (WritableValue<P>) cell.getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(((TableRow<I>)cell.getTableRow()).getItem());
    property.setValue(newValue);
}
```

Comment: How do i implement the update method? I'm new to javafx and do not know how exactly i can accomplish that..

Comment: I've already posted not one, but 2 versions of the `update` method... Without more information about the `TimeTable` class and the `cellValueFactory`s of the column I cannot tell you which one can be used.